# list of numbers to a stack back to a list

Tags: python-3.x

Imagine four railroad cars positioned on the input side of the track in the figure above, numbered 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively. Suppose we perform the following sequence of operations (which is compatible with the direction of the arrows in the diagram and does not require cars to "jump over" other cars):

As a result of these operations the original order of the cars, 1234, has been changed into 2431.

The operations above can be more concisely described by the code SSXSSXXX, where S stands for move a car from the input into the stack, and X stands for move a car from the stack into the output. Some sequences of S's and X's specify meaningless operations, since there may be no cars available on the specified track; for example, the sequence SXXSSXXS cannot be carried out. (Try it to see why.)

Write and test a function that emulates the train car switching:
    # [import statements]
    import q2_fun

```
# [constants]

# [rest of program code]
cars = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s_x = input("enter a code with s's and x's to move one stack to another")
list1 = q2_fun.train_swicth(cars, s_x)
print(list1)

from stack_array import Stack

def train_swicth(cars, s_x):

    s = Stack()
    list1 = []

    for i in range(len(s_x)):
        if s_x[i] == "s":
            a = s_x.append()
            s.push(a)
        elif s_x[i] == "x":
            b = s.pop()
            list1.append(b)


    return list1
```

I keep getting [] as the return and it should be 2431 with ssxssxxx. Can I get some help?

Comment: Please update your first paragraph in your question. As it stands now, it's almost impossible to understand your problem. (hint: periods is a nice invention)

Comment: @SteinarLima So _are_ plural verbs.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you right you could do:

```
def train_swicth(cars, s_x):
    i=0
    s=[]
    out=[]
    for c in s_x:
        if c=="s":
            s.append(cars[i])
            i+=1
        elif c=="x":
            out.append(s.pop())
    return out
```

as lists can be used as stacks with append as push-operation